# Rails 3.1 Devise -- How do I let users create an account with just an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

I'm using Rails 3.1 and Devise for registration, and would like to modify the Devise registration mechanism in such a way that an unregistered user may sign up with just an email address, without necessarily having to enter a user name and a password if she doesn't want to.  The behavior I want is that a) if no password is entered, I'd like the application to submit one automatically with the form, along with the password confirmation, and b) if no username is submitted, the application will submit a guess about the username based on the local part of the email address.  For example if you sign up with an email address like "SarahSilverman@gmail.com", without a user name or password, it will submit "SarahSilverman" as the default username, as well as a randomly generated password.  Here is a link to the code that pulls out the local part and generates a temporary password:

[app/helpers/application_helper.rb](https://github.com/fdschoeneman/skygodlin/blob/invitable-adding/app/helpers/application_helper.rb)

And here is the registration view:

[app/views/devise/registrations/html.haml])(https://github.com/fdschoeneman/skygodlin/blob/invitable-adding/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.haml)

Right now, the password fields are populating as intended, and submitting the password with the form.  The trouble is that the code I have isn't adding the name to the params, and submitting them along with the email when the user clicks signup.  Here is a gist of the relevant output from my logs:

[log/development.log](https://gist.github.com/1091092)

Thank you.

Comment: can you post all the code you have right now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the registrations controller.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    if params[:user] && !params[:user][:password]
        #params[:user][:password] = "Some password" 
        #should problem make this a random string but that's another question 
        super
    else
        super
    end
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

Some like this. Let me know if there are errors.

Comment: Thanks Codeglot.  Sadly, it still doesn't work.  I've set config/routes.rb with this:

Comment: Thanks Codeglot.  I've added this line to config/routes.rb, similar to this gist, but it still doesn't work:

https://gist.github.com/1091484

Comment: routes? You are using rails right? This belongs in a controller. See the first line of this code? `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`? Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Codeglot, thanks for your help.  I think I'm on the right track now.  Here's a gist of the registrations_controller.rb I wrote, and which solves most of what I'm trying to do:

[app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb](https://gist.github.com/1093932)

Answer (score 1):

Devise has different modules that will help you costumize some of the acctions the way you need, you may find them at the top of your User model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

The **validatable** module in in charge of the devise validation model so be sure to comment it out to remove the default devise validation options. After that you can create your own validation logic, or override the registration controller just as [Codeglot mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741296/rails-3-1-devise-how-do-i-let-users-create-an-account-with-just-an-email/6741376#6741376)

Comment: Hi Rogelio, I've commented out :validatable and used Codeglot's code and it still isn't putting the name and password and password_confirmation into the user params.